# Conditional Sorting in a mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation

I have a collection where some of the documents will have a field called `salesInfo` this field contains an object with a `salesEndDate` and a salesPrice.
Initially my query sorts the data based on a user selection, for example `{ price: 1 }` is the default sorting on the data.

I am trying to create a query that maintains the ability to sort by the default `{ price: 1 }` or the users selection. And adds the feature of always returning the products with a valid `salesInfo` field first in the array of documents returned. I thought this was a straightforward fix, to check the fields existence and check the value for salesEndDate is within acceptable range. However I am finding the validSalesInfo sort seems to override the initial sort.

I considered breaking these into separate queries or even separate arrays inside of the facet one for salesInventoryProducts and one for inventoryProducts but this makes pagination quite difficult.

So i am struggling to find a solution where there is a way to sort by data where all the sales products are first in the array and the non sales data is then sorted by the default/user selected sort.

This is my aggregation query:

```
const [{ inventoryProducts, inventoryCount }] = await inventory
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: query,
        },
        {
          $sort: filters?.sort ? parseSortOrder(filters.sort) : {},
        },
        {
          $facet: {
            inventoryProducts: [
              {
                $addFields: {
                  // Add salesInfoValid field to check if salesEndDate is valid
                  salesInfoValid: {
                    $cond: {
                      if: {
                        $and: [
                          // Check if salesInfo exists
                          { $ifNull: ['$salesInfo', false] },
                          // Check if salesEndDate is greater than or equal to the current date
                          { $gte: ['$salesInfo.salesEndDate', new Date()] },
                        ],
                      },
                      // If salesInfo is valid, set as salesInfo
                      then: '$salesInfo',
                      // Default value if salesInfo is not valid
                      else: -1,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              // Sort by salesInfoValid field
              { $sort: { salesInfoValid: -1 } },
              { $skip: page ? page * pageSize : 0 },
              { $limit: pageSize },
              {
                $lookup: {...},
              },
              {
                $set: {...},
              },
              {
                // remove the salesInfoValid field from the final output
                $project: {
                  salesInfoValid: 0,
                },
              },
            ],
            inventoryCount: [{ $count: 'total' }],
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray();
```

Ive tried conditionally sorting after the inital sort within the facet like this:

```
{
                // Add another sort condition based on salesInfoValid = -1 to apply sorting from the user
                $sort: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: ['$salesInfoValid', -1] },
                    then: { price: 1 },
                    else: { salesInfoValid: -1 },
                  },
                },
              },
```

but this seems to break things.

To sum up my question:
Can I sort a subset of the data within the steps of the facet?
How can I sort while still maintaining the products with  salesInfoValid : 1 first in the list returned?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you can create a new field that will contain the "sort" logic you required - then you can just sort on that like on any other field, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmpSortField: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$salesInfo",
                  false
                ]
              },
              false
            ]
          },
          then: {
            "$divide": [
              1,
              "$price"
            ]
          },
          else: {
            $subtract: [
              0,
              "$price"
            ]
          }
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      tmpSortField: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "tmpSortField"
  }
])
```

I'll briefly describe the logic of `tmpSortField`, if `salesInfo` exists then we set this field value to be `0 - price`, meaning that all objects with `salesInfo` will have a negative value, the bigger the price the more negative the number will be.

If `salesInfo` does not exist we set the `tmpSortField` value to `1/price` meaning all of these objects will have a positive value, The bigger the price the smaller the positive fraction will be.

Now we can just sort on `tmpSortField: 1` as it contains the "order" we want.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJ3LZhS8Y3p)